# Outputing \n instead of making a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need for the program to read each line of two text files and put each line together.
It works but the only problem is that it is outputting \n instead of making a new line.

code:

```
def user1():

    file=open('password.txt')
    passwords=file.readlines()
    g=[]
    for i in passwords:
        i.strip('\n')
        g.append(str(i))
    rfile=open('user.txt')
    users=rfile.readlines()
    r=[]
    for i in users:
        i.strip('\n')
        r.append(str(i))
    dictionaries=dict(zip(users,passwords))
    print(dictionaries)

user1()
```

So instead of looking like:

```
'ted123':'dd322'
'jnm443': 'dfvd3453'
```

It looks like this:

```
'ted123\n': 'dd322\n', 'jnm443\n': 'dfvd3453\n'
```

Comment: assign `i.strip('\n')` to a new variable. Strings are immutable. You can't alter them in place.

Comment: Can you escape the backslash `\\n`?

Comment: How about you convert the code like this?  `i = i.strip('\n')` or `r.append(str(i.strip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            yield line.strip()

result = dict(zip(get_data('user.txt'), get_data('password.txt')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that firstly you strip the lines and throw away the stripped value. strings are immutable, that means they cant be changed.

So

```
i.strip('\n')
```

is useless. It should be assigned to a variable.

```
i2 = i.strip('\n')
```

Also you are not using your the lists you built in the `zip` function call, you are zipping the files lines. These still have newline characters.

Changed code.

```
def user1():

    file = open('password.txt')
    passwords = file.readlines()

    g=[]
    for i in passwords:
        g.append(i.strip('\n'))

    rfile = open('user.txt')
    users = rfile.readlines()

    r = []    
    for i in users:
        r.append(i.strip('\n'))

    dictionaries = dict(zip(g, r))
    print(dictionaries)

user1()
```

The key things are that , we stash the stripped strings in the lists

```
r.append(i.strip('\n'))
```

and also use the lists in the `zip`

```
dictionaries = dict(zip(g, r))
```

You should also watch that you have not closed your files. To this use `with`, instead of manually calling close later. This is safer as an exception, in the intervening code would mean the close was not called. As far as an example of this.

```
with open('password.txt') as file:
    passwords = file.readlines()
```

Note that the lifetime of the file is controlled by the scope of the `with`, any code within that block has access to an open file. After the block it is closed.

If you wish to have each entry print on a separate line, don't try to rely on the newlines already in the file. Iterate over the `dict` and print each entry on a new line.

```
for name, pwd in dictionaries.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, pwd))
```

Of course, you can express this in much less code and without copying the lines to intermediate lists.

```
with open('user.txt') as fuser, open('password.txt') as fpass:

    def stripped(f):
        return map(str.strip, f)

    d = dict(zip(stripped(fuser), stripped(fpass)))

for name, pwd in d.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, pwd))
```